# how to deal quotes_historical_yahoo date time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use matplotlib.finance to download some data from yahoo finance.

```
from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
today=date.today()
start=(today.year-1,today.month,today.day)
quotes=quotes_historical_yahoo('AXP',start,today)
df=pd.DataFrame(quotes,columns=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Vol'])
df
```

The result is something like

```
      Date       Open        High         Low       Close       Vol
0   735536  87.376999   87.524947   88.264678   86.992340   5069300
1   735537  88.708520   88.718378   89.359479   88.146325   6848600
2   735540  89.083316   89.606057   89.961129   88.984686   3707900
```

I know the first column should be the date, but I don't know how to get the date time from it. How to deal with this column to make it like `"2011-01-01"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it myself, the key is `date.fromordinal()`+`date.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')`

```
    today=date.today()
    start=(today.year-1,today.month,today.day)
    quotes=quotes_historical_yahoo('AXP',start,today)
    fields=['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Vol']
    list1=[]
    for i in range(0,len(quotes)):
        x=date.fromordinal(int(quotes[i][0]))
        y=date.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')
        list1.append(y)
    df = pd.DataFrame(quotes,index=list1,columns=fields)
    df=df.drop(['date'],axis=1)
```